# How to sum price of products in cart per user

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to move some logics of my web shop application to database engine, so I figured that counting price of cart would be a good start. So I have a relation shown below with Cart_product table having foreign keys with Buyer and Product. The total price of cart for each user would be the price of each product in Cart_product multiplied by it's amount.
How and with what can I achieve this ? Trigger, procedure, cursor ? Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT Buyer_ID, SUM(Amount * Product.ProductPrice)
FROM Cart_product
LEFT JOIN Product on Cart_product.Product_ID = Product.Product_ID
GROUP BY Buyer_ID
```

would return how much each user's bought. What you do with it from there is up to you.

For a specific user:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount * Product.ProductPrice)
FROM Cart_product
LEFT JOIN Product on Cart_product.Product_ID = Product.Product_ID
WHERE Buyer_ID = XXX
GROUP BY Buyer_ID
```